# SOQL query on related records in Javascript(Visualforce page)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-debugging

I have written below query in Javascript(Visualforce page) and trying to access query result as shown below, but it is failing at second console log and giving error in developer console.

```
var user_query = "Select Id, contact.account.Name From User WHERE Id='" + user.userId + "' LIMIT 1";
var userQuery = sforce.connection.query(user_query);
var usrResult = userQuery.getArray('records')[0];
console.log('Working1***'+usrResult);
console.log('Working2***'+usrResult.contact.account.Name);
```

And below is the output from developer console.

```
Working1***{type:'User', Id:'00550000002pvqOAAQ', Contact:{type:'Contact', Id:null, Account:{type:'Account', Id:null, Name:'RUCKUS TEST VAR1', }, }, }
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'account' of undefined or null reference
```

Is there something I am missing while rendering Account name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. A property "Contact" is not the same as property "contact".
Access your property with

```
console.log('Working2***'+usrResult.Contact.Account.Name);
```

Your first console output gives you the correct cases for the properties.